# Multiple SessionAttributes into modelmap

Tags: java, spring, web, controller, mapping

I am pretty new to Spring, so sorry if this question may appear rather easy or obvious, but I was trying to look for an answer to this bus wasn't able to find it. So my question is how to use multiple SessionAttributes and get them into the map in one method?

i.e. I have a @Controller which uses SessionAttributes:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"name", "lastName", "birthDate"})
public class SearchController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/your-relatives")
    public String findRelatives(ModelMap model) {
        String name = (String) model.get("name");
        String lastName = (String) model.get("lastName");
        String birthDate = (String) model.get("birthDate");
        if (name.equals("John") && lastName.equals("Johnny")) {
            return "YES";
        }
        return "NO";
    }

}
```

But when I am trying to return "YES" in case when if is true, I get the error - There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available

It only works when using just one of attributes.

Comment: what exactly do you have in your sessoinAttributes `name` and `lastName`? And BTW what is `YES`? An html?

Comment: name and lastName are String values that I get from the user login. And YES for now is just simple hmtl file that returns text.

Comment: Make sure your String coming as user input exactly matches  `John` AND `Johnny` with J in uppercase. If case does not concern you , you can use `name.equalsIgnoreCase("John") && lastName.equalsIgnoreCase("Johnny")`

Comment: But if it doesn't match shouldn't I be returned  NO insead of YES? Because now all I get is error 500, no return value at all.

Comment: Technically `NO` should be an error page.

Comment: And it is when I map just one SessionAttribute and input doesn't match. But when I want to use both name and lastName it's not working at all.

Comment: Error 500 can be many things, could you please provide the log and stack trace error message, maybe you are getting a NullPointerException

Comment: You mean this?
ERROR 4084 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at lt.brigita.search.controller.SearchController.findRelatives(SearchController.java:47) ~[classes/:na]

line 47 is the one with if condition.